# How to fix the jQuery Image Accordion slider?

Tags: jquery, image, slider, accordion

I have one problem with my website. It uses accordion image slider, which is based on jquery. When you enter the website, first images opens fully, while the other images slide to the right side. OK, after that you can hover on any image and slide them, one by one. And if you put away the mouse, the accordion slider doesnt go back to its first state. It shows you thumbnails, but i want it to be where it was in first place, when you just entered the website... How do i fix this position of first image, so that if you slide thru the images, and then put away the mouse, first image goes back to its previous state?!

Here is the website: http://sunwind.lv

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce with chrome 15.

Comment: I use Chrome, and have the same thing. Just open the website, and you will see the first slide from the left in open state, while other slides moved to the right side, so that you can hover over them. After doing so, (hovering), the first slide doesn't go to its first state when you opened the website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'default' state is set in `setInitialPosition`, which is called in `root.mouseleave` (triggered when the mouse leaves the slider). I got this working as (I hope :) you want it just by changing the code to call `showSelected` instead in that case.

```
root.mouseleave(function ()
{
    ...
    if (!inHover)
    {
        showSelected(0);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, so smart :) But... nothing happens when i make changes to that part of code! Here is the code that i have in my accordion.js

   root.mouseleave(function(){
    inHover=false;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
     if(!inHover){
      setInitialPosition();
     }
    }, 150);
   });
   
  }

Comment: The whole .JS is here: http://wt.lv/sunwind/wp-content/themes/acoustic_v1.0/js/slider-accordion.js - please take a look where i have to put this code! Tried everything!

Comment: Really? I'm not sure what's going wrong; that code looks like the original I got from your site, and you should certainly get some sort of result - even if it is an error. :) Anyway, I've uploaded my modified version here http://meloncholy.com/tmp/slider-accordion.js

Comment: The JS link you've just posted seems to be to the original file - can't see the change I suggested in it? PS That's a killer domain. :)

Comment: Thats strange... OK, now uploaded your modified .JS - and dont see any results... or is it only me?

Comment: No, I don't think it's only you. I've refreshed the JS link you gave and it still looks like the old file. Is your host caching rather too enthusiastically?

Comment: loool... it was me! sorry mate :) i forgot that i had s subdomain, where was a copy of this website... lol, it was getting all this from that subdomain, where i had not updated the .JS :) stupid me! Wow, mate, please add me on skype: vladislav.ovcharov

Comment: Glad you figured it out, because server caching is really not my area... :) I don't really use Skype at the moment, but if you want you can email me through andrew at the domain above.